# QColorDialog Different on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qcolordialog

```
 void MainWindow::backgroundColor_screen_clicked()
{
    QColorDialog col;
    QColor color;
    color = col.getColor();
    pviz->setBackgroundColor(color.red()/255.0,color.green()/255.0,color.blue()/255.0);
    pviz2->setBackgroundColor(color.red()/255.0,color.green()/255.0,color.blue()/255.0);
    
}
```

When I use QColorDialog, I get a dialog form like this:

https://prnt.sc/10f7sy1

However, when I check the under QColorDialog examples I saw that form like this:

https://prnt.sc/10f7tlg

How can I use this color chart in my code too?

Comment: You might want to set (or unset) the [`DontUseNativeDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolordialog.html#ColorDialogOption-enum) option.

Comment: I set the DontUseNativeDialog and it didn't work. How can I unset it?

Comment: Sorry, it worked.